# I'm trying to pass event target values to another function

Tags: javascript, events, scope

I set up two events, one in feet and one in inches. I'm trying to grab the value of each event which would be feet and inches but I can't because of each event's scope. Is there a way to pass both values into my totalHeight function so that I can add the two values together?

```js
const justFeet = totalFeet.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    const heightInFeet = e.target.value;
    let displayFeet = document.createElement('h3')
    displayFeet.textContent = heightInFeet * 12
    // totalInches.appendChild(displayFeet)
})

const justInches = inches.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    const addOnInches = e.target.value;
    let displayInches = document.createElement('h3')
    displayInches.textContent = addOnInches
    // totalInches.appendChild(displayInches)
})
    
function totalHeight (feet, inches) {
    const finalTotal = feet + inches;
    let finalHeight = document.createElement('h3')
    finalHeight.textContent = finalTotal
    totalInches.appendChild(finalHeight)
}

totalHeight(displayFeet, displayInches)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of what it looks like you are trying to do. There's more you need to do, for example I used integers below but you could use floating numbers and perhaps add better handling for isNaN().

```
<html>
<style>
</style>

    Feet:<input id="feet" type="number"></input>
    Inches:<input id="inches" type="number"></input>
    <h3>Feet converted to inches: <span id="displayFeetToInches"></span></h3>
    <h3>Inches: <span id="displayInches"></span></h3>
    <h3>Total inches:<span id="finalHeight"></span></h3>

    <script>

        const feet = document.getElementById("feet");
        const inches = document.getElementById("inches");
        const total = document.getElementById("total");  //in inches
        const displayFeetToInches = document.getElementById("displayFeetToInches");  //in inches
        const displayInches = document.getElementById("displayInches");  //in inches

        const justFeet = feet.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
            console.log('justFeet');
            const heightInFeet = e.target.value;
            displayFeetToInches.textContent = heightInFeet * 12;
            totalHeight();
        })

        const justInches = inches.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
            console.log('justInches');
            const addOnInches = e.target.value;
            displayInches.textContent = addOnInches
            totalHeight();
        })

        function totalHeight (feet, inches) {
            console.log('totalinches');
            const ftToInches = displayFeetToInches.textContent;
            const addOn = displayInches.textContent;
            const finalTotal = parseInt(ftToInches) + parseInt(addOn);
            finalHeight.textContent = finalTotal
        }

    </script>
</html>
```